# Passing arguments with parentheses to Scala script contained in windows batch file

Tags: windows, shell, scala, command-line, batch-file

I'd like to put some Scala scripts into a batch file. If you just print the arguments, the canonical way would be like this:

```
::#!
@echo off
scala %0 %*
goto :eof
::!#
args foreach println
```

(This actually calls another batch script, scala.bat from the bin-directory of Scala). If I try to pass an argument containing parentheses to it, the windows command line interpreter complains with a syntax error:

```
printargs.bat "foo(bar)baz"
```

Strangely, if I create a scala file `printargs.scala` containing just `args foreach println`, this works correctly:

```
scala printargs.scala "foo(bar)baz"
```

So I assume this is not a bug in `scala.bat`. But what can I do?

Update: the actual error occurs in the following line in `scala.bat`:

```
set _ARGS=%*
```

with the error message

```
baz was unexpected at this time
```

If I change `scala.bat` that it does not use a local variable but use %* directly, it works correctly. So I [filed a bug-report](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4088). The question remains if there is a workaround for this problem until the bug is fixed.

Comment: You should add the code of scala.bat, so we can see the problem

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: `D:\Download>printargs foo(bar)baz` =>   
`baz was unexpected at this time`.   There is no error when I have "foo(bar)baz" quoted.  The message if from scala.bat, the real one  in Scala's bin/ directory.  It seems to be related to the closing paren ')' character.

Comment: Scala.bat: http://code.google.com/p/lighttexteditor/source/browse/trunk/light_edit/lib/scala/bin/scala.bat?r=51 Setting @echo on doesn't reveal much as it seems the CLI (cmd.exe?) execution and parsing are not in sync.  Adding any pauses ,etc in file makes it erratic.

Answer (score 0):

This bug does not occur in scala 2.8.1.final.
I would suggest using that version instead.

Comment: That was the version I am using. Strangely enough, when I just tried this again it worked correctly - no idea why. 8-{ But it seems at least Frayser in the comments to the question could also reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with Scala.. I'm currently having the same problem with passing an argument which contains parentheses into a grails command. Apparently this is a problem with the windows shell, have tried escaping the characters "(" but that does not work :/

Comment: Yes, the windows shell is beyond broken. But as mentioned in the question scala could use a workaround in scala.bat such that it would work correctly. Maybe grails could change the start script, too.